# How to preserve decimal precision in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, decimal, precision

I have a column with datatype `decimal(10,2)` in a table and when I try to update the column in a stored procedure I am losing the 2 digit precision.

If I update the field just as a single query, it works fine, but in a stored procedure it loses its precision.

Example:

```
UPDATE table
SET decimal(10,2) column = decimal(10, 2) column / 100
```

Example: `197.50` when updated results in `197.00`

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually dividing something by 100?

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Try /100.0 to force a floating point calculation.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Let's see the table definition and the actual UPDATE statement.  What you listed gives a syntax error for at least one flavor of SQL.

Comment: Yes I am diving something by 100 and I did try /100.00 as well. But it still does not work.

Comment: Also using sql server as my RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

I think, In your `RDMBS` a run-time conversion is automatically done on `column / 100` that:

- `column` is in decimal format and
- `100` is not in decimal format

So your solution is changing `100` to a decimal format like one of these:

- `100.00`
- `CAST(100 As Decimal(10, 2))`
- `(decimal(10, 2) 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue resolved. For some reason /100 does not work to keep the precision by when I tried * 0.01 it works.